# What does "Sport Utility Vehicle" actually mean?

Tags: etymology

Everyone knows what an SUV is, but what's with the name?  What does a vehicle that can't decide whether it wants to be a car or a truck have to do with either sports or utilities?

Comment: What does your research show?  Please include it in your question so the rest of our members know where you've already looked for your answer.

Comment: It's a term invented by the marketing department.  It doesn't have to mean anything, just sound "sexy" to the target market.  (Consider that people *want to believe* that they would be more sporty if they had a SUV.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, SUVs had four-wheel drive and lots of luggage room. The idea behind the name is that as well as regular driving, you also used SUVs for off-road travel (sport) and/or for carting stuff around (utility).

However, the advertising guys figured out how to sell SUVs to rich people who used them for driving around town, and since then they have been redesigned to greatly increase their comfort and have lots more luxury options available. And maybe now, some of them are not all that well-suited for their original purposes.

Comment: I think you need to leave out the "rich", as lots of SUVs get sold to middle to lower income people, some of whom are poor because they're making payments on the SUV and its fuel.

Comment: @jamesqf: I remember when SUVs were mainly for people who did off-road driving (my father was one), and then when they became a status symbol for middle-to-upper income people who didn't actually use them for off-road driving. The "rich" no longer applies, but it once did.

Comment: I doubt a 4X8' piece of plywood would fit in most modern SUV's, certainly not 3/4 ton of brick. For utility, you need to buy a pickup truck.

Comment: Look at the selling points in a [1983 ad](https://books.google.com/books?id=zNgDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA161&dq=sport+utility+vehicle&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBTg8ahUKEwi8kKvI--DGAhXF1YAKHepaChQ#v=onepage&q=sport%20utility%20vehicle&f=false) for the Chevy Blazer SUV, before SUVs were repositioned to sell to well-off suburbanites: *"Shift from freewheeling 2-wheel drive to 4-wheel drive High and back again at any speed."* – off-road capability; *"And with the optional rear seat folded down, you get a longer cargo length than any full-size sport utility vehicle."* – cargo-carrying capability.